# Assignment operator linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, overloading, assignment-operator

I am attempting to code an assignment operator for a linked list class in c++. The errors I'm getting say that "head" is undeclared, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to declare it. It's being used in other functions without a problem. Another error says my use of "this" is invalid.

```
template <class T>
SortedLinkList<T>& operator=(const SortedLinkList<T> & otherList)
{
    if(&otherList != this) {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        while(temp->getNext() != NULL) {
            head = head -> getNext();
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
        }
        count = 0;

        temp = otherList.head;
        while(temp != NULL) {
            insert(temp);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Is this inside of the class declaration or outside of it?

Comment: It is outside of the class declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` pointer is unavailable because your function signature does not resemble a member definition, you're missing the type scope resolution part of the signature:

```
template <class T>
SortedLinkList<T>& operator=(const SortedLinkList<T> & otherList)
```

should be:

```
template <class T>
SortedLinkList<T>& SortedLinkList<T>::operator=(const SortedLinkList<T> & otherList)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I am unclear on what the function declaration would look like though. It currently is this:

Comment: bool operator = (const SortedLinkList<T>& otherList);